# Room transition for glue down installation of 3mm LVT

Tags: flooring

I am installing 16" square 3mm thick glue down LVT in bathroom. There's a closet off the bathroom with a door. The current floor is ceramic tile. There's currently no transition from bathroom area to closet area (right side of image).

My original plan was to do the same with the LVP - no transition.

But as a novice installer, I am considering to add a threshold under the door into the closet. This will avoid the tricky cuts going around the walls. Also, those wall ends aren't square - making the cuts even more challenging.

I am considering using a t-molding transition like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/TruCore-Sandstorm-1-3-4-in-W-x-47-1-4-in-L-x-0-27-in-T-Vinyl-T-Molding-TC-801TM/315509874

[image]

Comment: Could you edit to make your question clear?

Comment: Also, I've seen thresholds designed for height transitions between two different types of flooring on display right by the LVF section in the big box stores. Don't remember more details.

Comment: It isn't clear what question you're asking.  Yes, a threshold would be the usual solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the closet is the area to the far right. Start at whatever part of the room is represented by the bottom of the drawing.  Remove all the baseboards and  undercut the closet door frame with a vibrating saw. This will give you a professional look and the non square walls are not an issue.  Use a scrap piece of flooring and lay the blade flat on the scrap to get the proper height.
The new pieces are thin enough that it should be easy to cut away just enough to tuck under the door frames. Then you need no transition.

I am concerned about the tile floor you are going over. If it is not smooth and with tiny grout lines, those features will eventually show through the new floor.

Comment: Only the closet had baseboard molding - which as been removed. I can't cut away where the door is because the surfaces are tiled. There is no molding. That's why it tricky and I'm considering adding a threshold to separate off the closet.